# Find the summation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}$

Tags: calculus

I need to find the summation of the above series in closed form.

Comment: $$\infty {{}}{{}}$$

Comment: You really don’t want to start at $n=1$.

Comment: Why, this series is convergence

Comment: oh , i ll edit it.

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{2}{n^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $$
\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
$$ and conclude by telescoping terms.
You end up with
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)
$$ and then let $N$ tend to $+\infty$ to obtain $\displaystyle  \frac12$ as the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1}$.

Now it is easy to adapt the previous steps to the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}.\quad$  :)!

You may start with $$ \frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

and then...

Comment: now, I have edited it. please see the new form of series.

Comment: @Ehegh Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Ehegh You should find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}=\frac{1}{2} $$...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2} - 1}}
={1 \over 4}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 3/2}\pars{n + 1/2}}
={1 \over 4}\,{\Psi\pars{3/2} - \Psi\pars{1/2} \over 3/2 - 1/2}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\bracks{\Psi\pars{3 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{\half}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
[Digamma Function $\color{#000}{\bf 6.3.1}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

> With the property $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} = \Psi\pars{z + 1} - {1 \over z}}$ we'll have 
>   $$
> \Psi\pars{3 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{\half}
> =\Psi\pars{3 \over 2} - \bracks{\Psi\pars{\half + 1} - {1 \over 1/2}}
> =2
> $$

By replacing in $\pars{1}$:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2} - 1}}
={1 \over 4}\times2=\color{#66f}{\Large\half}
$$